# Comparing two datagridview and returning a datagridview by matching a column C#

Tags: c#, excel, import, datagridview, compare

C# WindowsForms.
Proyect: Import 2 Excel and choose the sheet that holds the table, then compare the column "Code" at both files and show the matching ones with their info on third dataGridView.

```
DGV1                
Code    Date        Tipe    Price   Account
3367    02-feb-18   NEW     25      N/A
8543    04-feb-18   NEW     25      N/A
3367    05-feb-18   RENEW   50      N/A
5542    07-feb-18   NEW     75      N/A
1069    27-jan-18   NEW     25      N/A

DGV2                
City    Code
Texas   3367
Texas   8543
Texas   5542
Texas   8673            

DGV3                
Code    Date        Tipe    Price   Account
3367    02-feb-18   NEW     25      N/A
3367    05-feb-18   RENEW   50      N/A
8543    04-feb-18   NEW     25      N/A
5542    07-feb-18   NEW     75      N/A
```

At the moment im tring with this guide:
https://forgetcode.com/CSharp/1508-Comparing-two-datatables-and-returning-a-datatable-by-matching-one-or-more-columns-using-LINQ#
But i dont get it yet. Hope someone can help me with the remaining part as well with an explanation.

```
private void btnSelect1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
          openfiledialog1.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm";

          if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
          {
               this.tBox1.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
          }

          string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
          con.Open();

          dropdown_sheet1.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
          dropdown_sheet1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
          dropdown_sheet1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}

public void btnLoad1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
          OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + dropdown_sheet1.SelectedValue + "]", con);
          DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
          sda.Fill(dt1);

          foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
          {
               dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}

private void btnSelect2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          OpenFileDialog openfiledialog2 = new OpenFileDialog();
          openfiledialog2.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm";

          if (openfiledialog2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
          {
               this.tBox2.Text = openfiledialog2.FileName;
          }

          string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
          con.Open();

          dropdown_sheet2.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
          dropdown_sheet2.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
          dropdown_sheet2.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}

public void btnLoad2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
          OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + dropdown_sheet2.SelectedValue + "]", con);
          DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
          sda.Fill(dt2);

          foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
          {
               dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
          }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

I have already the import and sheet selection, but i dont understand the compare.

Answer (score 1):

get data of both data grids as a data table.`

```
public DataTable getLinq(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
        {
            DataTable dtMerged = (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                  join b in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                  on a["code"].ToString() equals b["code"].ToString()
                                  into g
                                  where g.Count() > 0
                                  select a).CopyToDataTable();

            return dtsimilar;
        }`

       set dtsimilar as data source for  third grid
```

Comment: I got the data of both datatable, but when i try the compare it doesnt show any result at the datagridview

Comment: can you show me the code where do you call this function.